# R: recursive indexing failed at level 2

Tags: rstudio

I created a list of matrix, I want to be able to apply operations with they, one thing I want to do is combine them  using operator like cbin and rbind among others, one way to do it it's the next, but i just want to save the matrixs in the list and apply operations without writing everyone.

```
'Combinedmatrix<-cbind(elementlist[[1]],...,elementlist[[n]])'
```

Is there a way to do the same instead writing each element of the list?
I tried the next

```
'(i in 1:length(list)){combinedmatrix<-cbind(list[[i]])}'
```

in this case it only takes the last element and do nothing more,
the other way I tried was:

```
'i<-1:length(list)'
'combinedmatrix<-cbind(list[[i]])}'
```

in this case appear

```
'Error in list[[i]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` from the `purrr` package. Assuming `mlist` is your list of matrices:

```r
library(purrr)
reduce(mlist,rbind)
```

With example data:

```r
> mlist <- list(matrix(1:9,nrow=3),matrix(1:9,nrow=3),matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
> mlist
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9


> reduce(mlist,rbind)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    4    7
 [2,]    2    5    8
 [3,]    3    6    9
 [4,]    1    4    7
 [5,]    2    5    8
 [6,]    3    6    9
 [7,]    1    4    7
 [8,]    2    5    8
 [9,]    3    6    9
```